# With the new ATS feature, will an app be rejected by apple for not using https?

Tags: https, ios9

Apple has made it necessary to use https for server communications with iOS 9 but my server cannot have SSL implemented right now. I have disabled the ATS feature for my app. Will this cause my app to be rejected by apple?

With the new ATS feature, will an app  be rejected by apple for not using https ?

Answer (score 1):

I thought to make an update on this as things have changed since the 2016 Apple WWDC.

From the start of 2017, Apple will Reject your apps if your apps does not confirm to ATS. In simple terms, if your app does *not* use https, then your app will get rejected from the appstore.

If you really can not convert to https, then you need to explain why you can not do so. Otherwise, Apple will reject your apps!

Comment: Correct, but a official link to the document describing this issue would be helpful for all the other users.

Comment: Hi Paul, I've listened to their WWDC tech talk on ATS and got the info. Can't remember a document though.

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm sending you the link below to their WWDC talk related to security where they discuss ATS.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/

Answer (score 0):

No, your won't be rejected for not supporting SSL TLSv1.2, but one should really think twice before disabling ATS, and also, you can list all your domains to be exceptions to ensure all other traffic is secure.

Comment: Hi Simon. Your statement is true as of now. But just need to make it clear that Apple will start rejecting apps without ATS from the end of 2016!